# Vba Excel, Problems with the current date

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am searching for the date at the time of opening my document, in which I sent the document by mail, but days later I printed a date that does not match the current one. And it prints the date on which I send this document

```py
Sub GetCurrentDate()
    Dim S$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.fechadehoy.com/venezuela", False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .body.innerHTML = S
        ConjuntoB = .getElementById("fecha").innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Is there any way this does not happen? And daily can I extract the date from the web?

Comment: Your code works well.

Comment: Cannot reproduce so VTC as off topic